# Angular 2 Chart.js and NG2-Charts Not Binding Data Objects After Updates To Project

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular-cli, ng2-charts

I have been working on a project in Angular-2 using the starter project found [here](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/tree/master/Angular2_CLI_Full_Project),

The project worked great till I made some updates to my environment and project. Now the data objects won't bind. It seems like charts.js is not being imported into the project correctly.

I did see in the docs [Here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) it states to embed the charts.js file into the html file. This is done in the example by adding node_modules to the src. I was under the impression this was a huge no no! I did try this but can't get the app to expose the file when referenced in that way.

Current versions

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.17
node: 6.7.0
os: darwin x64 Sierra
npm: 3.10.3
```

After updating to

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17"
```

I started getting errors. I went ahead and updated everything to the latest versions in hope this would clear them. it appears that Charts.js is not being imported to the project after updates. Charts were displaying fine before updating angular-cli. Now that I have updated everything even rolling back won't seem to fix the problem.

Basically anywhere in my component.ts file that I bind a data object to the chart it gives me errors saying that the data object is not a known property off basic-chart. I believe this is a versioning issue and it is not being imported into the project correctly after updates.

I was importing the charts like this in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ],
```

Then in app.module.ts

```
import { ChartsModule }                 from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    Ng2BootstrapModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
```

Current versions I am running,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.4.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
```

Here are a few of the errors,

```
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'datasets' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("iv>
                <div class="chart-wrapper p-x-1">
                    <base-chart class="chart" [ERROR ->][datasets]="lineChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineC"): DashboardComponent@19:46
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'labels' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("ss="chart-wrapper p-x-1">
                    <base-chart class="chart" [datasets]="lineChart1Data" [ERROR ->][labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineChart1Colours" [legend]="line"): DashboardComponent@19:74
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("                  <base-chart class="chart" [datasets]="lineChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [ERROR ->][options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineChart1Colours" [legend]="lineChart1Legend" [chartType]="l"): DashboardComponent@19:102
Can't bind to 'colors' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'colors' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("class="chart" [datasets]="lineChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [ERROR ->][colors]="lineChart1Colours" [legend]="lineChart1Legend" [chartType]="lineChart1Type" (chartHover)="c"): DashboardComponent@19:132
Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'legend' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("eChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineChart1Colours" [ERROR ->][legend]="lineChart1Legend" [chartType]="lineChart1Type" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartCl"): DashboardComponent@19:161
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'chartType' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("hart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineChart1Colours" [legend]="lineChart1Legend" [ERROR ->][chartType]="lineChart1Type" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
"): DashboardComponent@19:189
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no longer the selector `base-chart` valid.

Per ng2-charts [changelog](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

> base-chart component became baseChart directive so you need to convert

```
<base-chart...></base-chart>
```

to

```
<canvas baseChart...></canvas>
```

and most probably wrap in

```
<div style='display:block'>...</div>
```

See **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/edlnC7yLjpSmLF1RFjVB?p=preview)**

Comment: So where is says all chart type names lower cased (because of chart.js 2 changes). Does that mean base-chart should be basechart? Also should I indeed move chart.js into the assets folder so I can import it in the html file?

Comment: @wuno - I ended up having to move chart.js into my assets folder to import in index.html...but then ran into problems with require...so ended up importing Chart.bundle.js from chart.js/dist insteas of chart.js/src.

Comment: Bravo for plunker example, it made difference.